# Setting up Kubernetes Autoscaling with Custom Metrics

Tags: kubernetes, metrics, autoscaling

I am trying to set up autoscaling on a Kubernetes 1.2.3 (beta) cluster based on custom metrics. (I already tried CPU-based autoscaling on the cluster, and it worked fine.)

I tried to follow their [custom metrics proposal](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/proposals/custom-metrics.md), but I'm having problems in creating the necessary set-up.

This is what I have done so far:

1. Added a custom metrics annotation to the pod spec being deployed
   (similar to the configuration provided in their proposal):

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: ReplicationController
   metadata:
     name: metrix
     namespace: "default"
   spec:
     replicas: 1
     template:
       metadata:
         labels:
           app: metrix
         annotations:
           metrics.alpha.kubernetes.io/custom-endpoints: >
             [
               {
                 "api": "prometheus",
                 "path": "/status",
                 "port": "9090",
                 "names": ["test1"]
               },
               {
                 "api": "prometheus",
                 "path": "/metrics",
                 "port": "9090"
                 "names": ["test2"]
               }
             ]
       spec:
         containers:
         - name: metrix
           image: janaka/prometheus-ep:v1
           resources:
             requests:
               cpu: 400m
   ```
2. Created a Docker container tagged `janaka/prometheus-ep:v1` (local) running a Prometheus-compatible server on port 9090, with `/status` and `/metrics` endpoints
3. Enabled custom metrics on the kubelet by appending `--enable-custom-metrics=true` to `KUBELET_OPTS` at `/etc/default/kubelet` (based on [the kubelet CLI reference](http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kubelet/)) and restarted the kubelet

All pods (in `default` and `kube-system` namespaces) are running, and the heapster pod log doesn't contain any 'anomalous' outputs either (except for a small glitch at startup, due to temporary unavailability of InfluxDB):

```
$ kubesys logs -f heapster-daftr

I0427 05:07:45.807277       1 heapster.go:60] /heapster --source=kubernetes:https://kubernetes.default --sink=influxdb:http://monitoring-influxdb:8086
I0427 05:07:45.807359       1 heapster.go:61] Heapster version 1.1.0-beta1
I0427 05:07:45.807638       1 configs.go:60] Using Kubernetes client with master "https://kubernetes.default" and version "v1"
I0427 05:07:45.807661       1 configs.go:61] Using kubelet port 10255
E0427 05:08:15.847319       1 influxdb.go:185] issues while creating an InfluxDB sink: failed to ping InfluxDB server at "monitoring-influxdb:8086" - Get http://monitoring-influxdb:8086/ping: dial tcp xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8086: i/o timeout, will retry on use
I0427 05:08:15.847376       1 influxdb.go:199] created influxdb sink with options: host:monitoring-influxdb:8086 user:root db:k8s
I0427 05:08:15.847412       1 heapster.go:87] Starting with InfluxDB Sink
I0427 05:08:15.847427       1 heapster.go:87] Starting with Metric Sink
I0427 05:08:15.877349       1 heapster.go:166] Starting heapster on port 8082
I0427 05:08:35.000342       1 manager.go:79] Scraping metrics start: 2016-04-27 05:08:00 +0000 UTC, end: 2016-04-27 05:08:30 +0000 UTC
I0427 05:08:35.035800       1 manager.go:152] ScrapeMetrics: time: 35.209696ms size: 24
I0427 05:08:35.044674       1 influxdb.go:177] Created database "k8s" on influxDB server at "monitoring-influxdb:8086"
I0427 05:09:05.000441       1 manager.go:79] Scraping metrics start: 2016-04-27 05:08:30 +0000 UTC, end: 2016-04-27 05:09:00 +0000 UTC
I0427 05:09:06.682941       1 manager.go:152] ScrapeMetrics: time: 1.682157776s size: 24
I0427 06:43:38.767146       1 manager.go:79] Scraping metrics start: 2016-04-27 05:09:00 +0000 UTC, end: 2016-04-27 05:09:30 +0000 UTC
I0427 06:43:38.810243       1 manager.go:152] ScrapeMetrics: time: 42.940682ms size: 1
I0427 06:44:05.012989       1 manager.go:79] Scraping metrics start: 2016-04-27 06:43:30 +0000 UTC, end: 2016-04-27 06:44:00 +0000 UTC
I0427 06:44:05.063583       1 manager.go:152] ScrapeMetrics: time: 50.368106ms size: 24
I0427 06:44:35.002038       1 manager.go:79] Scraping metrics start: 2016-04-27 06:44:00 +0000 UTC, end: 2016-04-27 06:44:30 +0000 UTC
```

However, the custom endpoints are not being scraped. (I verified it by adding stderr logs for startup and endpoint handlers of my server; only the server initialization logs are displayed on kubectl logs of the pod.)

As I'm a newbie to Kubernetes, any help is appreciated.

(From what I understood from the proposal as well as [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/18352), we don't have to run a separate Prometheus collector in the cluster as **cAdvisor** should already pull data from the endpoints defined in the pod spec. Is this true, or do I need a separate Prometheus collector as well?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [custom metrics proposal](https://github.com/mwielgus/kubernetes.github.io/blob/custom-metrics/docs/user-guide/horizontal-pod-autoscaling/index.md) is out of date.

Please refer to the [user guide](https://github.com/mwielgus/kubernetes.github.io/blob/custom-metrics/docs/user-guide/horizontal-pod-autoscaling/index.md#support-for-custom-metrics), which is currently under review.

Comment: have you managed to get custom metrics like this? the `hostPort: 8080` part looks strange, how do you run multiple pods with a config like this on the same host?

Comment: You don't, since it's the same port, but it seems you can use pod ip https://github.com/google/cadvisor/issues/1212

Comment: I have been trying to follow the user guide for the past week and have not managed to get anything working for custom metrics.

The guide assumes way too much context.  It needs to provide the assumed context in a way that would (almost) allow a series of copy/paste operations to get a functional example.